# Symfony 1.4: autoload modules' lib folders

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, autoload

how can I autoload my modules' lib folders in my Symfony 1.4 projects? Probably you know that problem:

If I create plugins, I store base-classes for my modules' actions in the lib folder. Each actions-class stored in `actions/actions.class.php` inherits from that base-class. This allows overriding the plugin-actions at project level:

```
myModule
   actions
      actions.class.php
   lib
      BasemyModuleActions.class.php
```

But unfortunately, Symfony doesn't autoload `BasemyModuleActions` and you have to include the respective file manually:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) .'/lib/BasemyModuleActions.class.php');
class myModuleActions extends BasemyModuleActions
{
}
```

This works, but it is really annoying. Moreover I want to put more files in the modules' lib folders, e.g. forms.

Is there a way to add those directories to the autoloader?

Storing forms in their related modules would good for me, since I only reuse the same form for different modules in few cases.

Is your solution also compatible with the Doctrine form-generation task? I.e. is Symfony aware of the existing form, or will it be created again if it is moved out of `lib/form/doctrine`? (No problem, if you can't answer that. But it would be nice if you know a workaround in this case)

Comment: As far as I know it should be autoloaded. Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Look at the example above. You will find that `require_once` workaround even in the actions of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. I'm sure they aren't autoloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page:

http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/14-Other-Configuration-Files

It describes an autoload.yml file, which configures symfony to look for classes in different directories.

Symfony wouldn't autoload my **/apps/app_name/lib/*.*** classes, but does so after creating **/config/autoload.yml** file with the following content:

```
autoload:
  # project
  project:
    name:           project
    path:           %SF_LIB_DIR%
    recursive:      true
    exclude:        [model, symfony]

  project_model:
    name:           project model
    path:           %SF_LIB_DIR%/model
    recursive:      true

  # application
  application:
    name:           application
    path:           %SF_APP_LIB_DIR%
    recursive:      true

  modules:
    name:           module
    path:           %SF_APP_DIR%/modules/*/lib
    prefix:         1
    recursive:      true
```

Which the above page describes as the default config.

Comment: I will try that soon, but at the moment I don't have much time. However I wonder how it's possible that this works. As you said it should already be the default config. Therefore, adding that autoload.yml shouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand it this is a chicken and egg issue with the autoloader and main controller flow.

The prefix: 1 in the default autoload.yml indicates that these classes are only available to be autoloaded if 'in' the current module.

The way the current module is determined is by looking at the actionStack.

The module/action is added to the actionStack after checking to see if it exists.

Unfortunately to determine if an action exists symfony loads the actions.class.php

Hence you need to have the explicit, require_once.

If you get rid of the prefix: 1 and your module is part of your application (not loaded from a plugin) you will not need the require once.

If the module is part of a plugin, you would need to mess with sfPluginConfiguration to have it load the appropriate classes without prefix.

Both methods are problematic as there could be clashes between class names in various modules.